# AJAX send method and button visibility

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, angularjs

So, there's a textarea and under that send button on panel wich is showing after puting first character, isButtonVisible() method controlls this. It sends text from textarea by AJAX send() method to data.php, where data from textarea has to be saved in .txt document. .js file name is ng-controllers.js Can anyone help me with this? I have no experience in  angular.js

Here's how my HTML file look like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">  
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="pl" lang="pl" ng-app="Textarea"><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"><style type="text/css">@charset "UTF-8";[ng\:cloak],[ng-cloak],[data-ng-cloak],[x-ng-cloak],.ng-cloak,.x-ng-cloak,.ng-hide{display:none !important;}ng\:form{display:block;}.ng-animate-block-transitions{transition:0s all!important;-webkit-transition:0s all!important;}.ng-hide-add-active,.ng-hide-remove{display:block!important;}</style>

<title>Angular - Textarea</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./Angular - Textarea_files/style.css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="./Angular - Textarea_files/jquery.min.js"></script><style type="text/css"></style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="./Angular - Textarea_files/angular.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="./Angular - Textarea_files/ng-controllers.js"></script> 

</head>
<body style="padding:0px; margin:0px;" onload="">
<div class="Cont" ng-controller="TextAreaCtrl as ctrl">
    <div class="TextAreaCont">
        <textarea ng-model="text" placeholder="Write something..." style="margin: 0px; height: 106px; width: 795px;"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="ButtonCont" ng-show="ctrl.isButtonVisible()">
        <button ng-click="ctrl.send()">Send</button>
    </div>
</div>


</body></html>
```

Comment: i have no idea how to make it in angular

Comment: So you want someone to write the ajax post in angular, write the server side bit that saves it in a .txt file for you?

Comment: no. just ajax post in angular, maybe how should look data.php to receive it  and this button visible thing. I need help with it cause i have no idea how to do it. i'm seriously desperate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ajax calls in angualr use the `$http` provider
[full documentation here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

It's very close to how you do $.ajax in jquery, i.e.

```
var httpPost = $http({
    method: "post",
    url: "example.com/posts",
    data: {
        // some data here
    }
});
```

Then you assign a function to run on success

```
httpPost.success(
    function( html ) {
        // do something here 
    }
);
```

Comment: thanks. maybe u will know something about that is button visible?